# Is possible to have a field dependend on other field?

Tags: 2sxc

I have some dropdown list fields with countries, states, and cities but i need to have each one related to the other (dril Down) when you add a new item.

I need to have countries, when you select one country, i need another field be filtered with states, maybe somebody have an example form this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't have an example to show directly, but it can be done fairly easily AFAIK. Basically your first dropdown is on a field - let's call it `CountryField` (you shouldn't use the term field, but I'm using it here to ensure you understand the instruction).

To filter the entities, you create a query with visual query to get only the ones matching the url parameter - use a ValueFilter or RelationshipFilter and check that it's equal to `[QueryString:Country]`. Add a test-value to your query (the test values are to the right) till you're sure it works.

Then in the second dropdown you create an entity-query picker and specify that in the parameters it should use `Country=[CountryField]` (the thing from step 1).

Basically now when the first dropdown changes, the second one should auto-re-request the data based on the first one.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks iJungleBoy, thats what im exactly doing but is not working.

Just additional information, my CountryField, is an entity field, so filter Country=[CountryField] should point to an entity-field.

Today i tested with a simple txt field, and worked, but problem comes with value for filter comes from another entity field.

Comment: pls check what parameter is sent over the network, then use that as your testvalue to see what you must change. you may have to compare with EntityGuid instead of title or something.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have checked the network, but when you try to select the entity field, there is not a call in network. When filter value comes from a text field (CountryTextField), you have a server call like "Default?includeGuid=true&Country=MyTestText", but when filter uses a entity field (CountryField), there is not any call to the server. Maybe this is a bug, because call to the server is not triggered.

Comment: are you using the old or new UI?

Comment: Im using old UI, because new UI have some issues when setting entity fields. I reported in github issues.

Comment: ok. just fyi: I'll be on vacation starting this evening, so I won't be able to answer anything for 3+ weeks.